# select data from database with values from multiple checkbox array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, mysqli, checkbox

This is the code i m getting error with:

```
function sanitizeString($var)
{
    $var = trim($var);
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    return $var;
}
$errors = array();
$query = "";
if (isset($_POST["tests_list"])) {
    $test_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitizeString($_POST["tests_list"]));
    $can_ids = $_POST["checkCandidate"];
    $status = "active";
    foreach ($can_ids as $can_value) {
        $sel = mysqli_query($con, 'select * from assign_table where candidate_id="' .$can_value.'" and test_id="$test_id"');
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sel)>0){
            $errors[] = $can_value  . " already assigned<br>";
        }else{
            $query .= "insert into assign_table(test_id, candidate_id, status) values('$test_id', '" . $can_value . "', '$status');";
        }
    }
    if(count($errors)===0){
        if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $query)) {
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "error";
        }
    }else{
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Direct Access Not Allowed";
}
```

I want to check if selected candidate already assigned or not. If a candidate is already assigned to test, it should display message already assigned, else insert candidate to `assign_table`, but its not validating the select query.
Anyone can help?

Comment: `$test_id` in your select string (Notice the single quotes) is not being concated, so it's putting a literal `test_id = "$test_id"` in the query string.

Comment: You are also wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping some of your values at all. It's also must better than using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` (which you only do for one of your two values).

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Remove your `sanitizeString()`-function. If you use prepared statements, you don't need to escape your data at all. Also, you shouldn't encode your data (with `htmlentities()`) when you save the data. You should save it "as is" and encode it when you output the data instead.

Comment: If there are multiple comma separated values coming in `$test_id` and `$can_ids` then you should use `$sel = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM assign_table WHERE candidate_id IN("' .$can_value.'") AND test_id IN("$test_id")');`

Comment: @AhmedNumaan - Your suggestion would produce: `IN("1, 2, 3, ...")`  which would make it one single value. It should be `IN (1, 2, 3, ...)` (without quotes around it all) or `IN ("1", "2", "3", ...)` (quotes around every value). The OP shouldn't use the variable directly in the query either way since that's super insecure. Also, it seems like the OP actually wants to check each ID separately. Not all together.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Agree!

Comment: Thanks @FrankerZ, Now its working.